# Jasmine test for scope methods fails

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, bdd, spy

I have an spec that test's if the method in scope was called (see below)

```
describe("Event Module tests", function () {

    var scope, simpleController;

    beforeEach(module('SimpleApplication'));
    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        simpleController = $controller("SimpleController", {
            $scope: scope
        });
    }));


    it("Scope function should be triggered", function () {

        spyOn(scope, "trigger");

        scope.trigger();//invoke the function on controller

        expect(scope.trigger).toHaveBeenCalled();//Passes
        expect(scope.isTriggered).toBeTruthy();//Fails

    });

});
```

Application Code(Code to be tested):

```
angular
    .module("SimpleApplication", [])
    .controller("SimpleController", function ($scope) {

        $scope.message = "Hello World";

        $scope.isTriggered = false;

        $scope.trigger = function() {
            $scope.isTriggered = true;
        };
    });
```

Jasmine reports that "Expected false to be truthy.". How come ? since the method sets it to true !!

**Update:**

For some reason, SpyOn was mutating my object to something it was intended for. So below piece of code works good

```
it("Scope function should be triggered", function () {

            scope.trigger();//invoke the function on controller

            expect(scope.isTriggered).toBeTruthy();//Now Passes

        });
```

Comment: It's probably obvious to someone else what's wrong here, but did you realize that you can execute your unit tests in a browser, like Chrome or Firefox, and step through your code to see what it is doing?  You can execute Karma on the command line and use the debugger in the browser to do this.

Comment: @DavidM.Karr Some way or the other your suggestions lead me to the answer. `Spyon` was mutating my `trigger` function, so indeed it did not do what i wanted. So removed that piece of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`spyOn` doesn't call your method. It just spies. If you want it to be called you have to add something:

```
spyOn(scope, "trigger").andCallThrough()
```